# How do I rectify 'Unexpected Indent" error in Python?

Tags: python, indentation

Here is my code:

```
def c_to_f(c):    
    f = c*(9/5) + 32
    return f
    
c = input("Please enter the temperature in celsius: ")
    if c< -273.15:
        return "That temperature is not achievable."
    else:
        return f
print("Here's your temperature in Fahrenheit: ", c_to_f(c))
```

The terminal, on executing this code displays:

```
if c< -273.15:                                                                                                                            
    ^                                                                                                                                         
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

How do I proceed to solve this error?

Comment: it means your ```if c< -273.15:``` loop is indented  when it shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

Need to fix the line above the traceback line it's throwing:

```
def c_to_f(c):    
    f = c*(9/5) + 32
    print(f)

    # the input line here needs to be indented to be consistent within your code block and consider adding an int() if you are expecting a value
    c = int(input("Please enter the temperature in celsius: "))
    if c < -273.15:
        print("That temperature is not achievable.")
    else:
        print(f)

    # and the print() statement needs to be indented as well 
    print("Here's your temperature in Fahrenheit: ", c_to_f(c))
```

See this [link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), it follows the PEP8 rules for indentation (4 spaces).

Comment: The `return f` just stops all, I thinkg this isn't the good function

Comment: true, should be using `print()` instead to prevent the function from ending before it reaches the if/else statements.